# Will it be fine if we use msse and msse2 option of gcc in RTOS devices

Tags: c, performance, gcc

As per my knowledge `msse` and `msse2` option of `gcc` will improve the performance by performing arithmetic operation faster. And also I read some where like it will use more resources like registers, cache memory.

What about the performance if we use the executable generated with these options on RTOS devices(like vxworks board) ?

Comment: SSE is an x86 instruction set extension. If your device isn't x86, you can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS must support SSE(2) instructions for your application to work correctly. It would seem, from googling, that VcWorks supports this (and it's not really that hard, all it takes is that the OS has a 512 byte save-area per task that uses SSE/SSE2 - given the right circumstances, it can be allocated on demand, but it's often easier to just allocate it to all tasks]. Saving/restoring SSE registers is done "on demand", that is, only when a task different from the previous one to use SSE is using SSE instructions, is it necessary to save the registers. The OS will use a special interrupt(trap) to indicate that "a new task is trying to use SSE instructions.

So, as long as the processor supports it, you should be fine.

Comment: Plus, as long as the OS supports it, the "cost" is the same, whether you use it or not.

Comment: Ehm, no. If you don't use FP/SSE instructions, there is no cost at all - since it's "on-demand" saving of the FP context - that works really well for most applications, as most things don't use much floating point or SIMD instructions. The OS will only save/restore the state when you actually USE it.

Comment: I wouldn't know how this is supposed to work (TS flag maybe?), but I'll take your word on it. :-)

Comment: It's been a while, so I had to look it up. TS flag it is.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be able to directly answer your question, but here are a couple things I do know that may be of use:

- SSE, SSE2, etc. must be supported/implemented by the processor for them to have any affect in the first place.
- There are specific functions you can call that use these extended instructions for mathematical operations. These functions operate on wider data types or perform an operation on a set efficiently.
- Enabling the options in GCC may use the previous APIs/builtins automatically. This is the part I am unsure about.